# Why there is no TypeScript Interface definition for NodeJS core modules?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am new to NodeJS and TypeScript so this question may be stupid but still it kind of bugs me. I have installed typings for NodeJS generatly they consist of the lattest node.ts.d. The problem I see is that when I create instance of a NodeJS core module (*example `var fs = require("fs");`*) I can't specify `var fs` to be of concrete NodeJS module type (*example `fs:IFileSystem = require("fs")`*). Question is why node.ts.d does not contain such interface is it intentional or what is the reason not to include such NodeJS core modules interfaces which seams logical ?

Comment: use the import syntax: `import * as fs from "fs"`. You don't need to manually assign a type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `import` to import modules:

```
import fs = require('fs');
```

And you will get autocompletion (if corresponding typings are installed).

Comment: I am trying to understand more the reason why such interface is not created, instead just to solve the problem with auto-completion. Kind of understand it better instead of just using it.